# Rails 4 Virtual records (not virtual attributes) - possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am implementing a basic tagging feature to my rails app, and I want to have two kinds of tags:

- A **general** type (ie user Greg is tagged as "awesome" via basic `belongs_to` / `has_many` relation between `User` and `Tag` models)
- A **"virtual"** tag type, based on the presence of a record *in another model all together* (ie Greg purchased Widget X, via a `belongs_to` / `has_many` relation between `User` and `Purchase` models).

I want to be able to query `user.tags` and get both tag type for a user (basic and virtual). If the user has purchased something, I want `user.tags` to yield a "virtual" tag for that purchase (ideally based on the same class as the general tags).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So my motivation for trying to do this was to keep my database normalized (ie not storing the same piece of information in two places).

However, I came to the realization that in the real world, sometimes it makes sense to sacrifice some normalization for better performance and reduced complexity.

So what I ended up doing was keeping these special tag models "in sync" with their various counterpart models elsewhere in the app via model callbacks and `dependent: destroy` relations.